# Pandas Confusion - My apply() is returning a series and I don't understand why

Tags: python, pandas

As part of my ongoing quest to get my head around pandas I am confronted by a surprise series. I don't understand how and why the output is a series - I was expecting a dataframe. If someone could explain what is happening here it would be much appreciated.

ta, Andrew

Some data:

```
        hash                                         email       date                                           subject  subject_length
0  65319af6e                        jbrockmendel@gmail.com 2020-11-28      REF-IntervalIndex._assert_can_do_setop-38112              44
1  0bf58d8a9                     simonjayhawkins@gmail.com 2020-11-28  DOC-add-contibutors-to-1.2.0-release-notes-38132              48
2  d16df293c  45562402+rhshadrach@users.noreply.github.com 2020-11-28        TYP-Add-cast-to-ABC-Index-like-types-38043              42
...
```

Some Code:

```
def my_function(row):
    output = row['email'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending = False).head(3)
    return output

top_three = dataframe.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1M')).apply(my_function)
```

Some Output:

```
date                                                         
2020-01-31  jbrockmendel@gmail.com                               159
            50263213+MomIsBestFriend@users.noreply.github.com     44
            TomAugspurger@users.noreply.github.com                41
...
2020-10-31  jbrockmendel@gmail.com                               170
            2658661+dsaxton@users.noreply.github.com              23
            61934744+phofl@users.noreply.github.com               21
2020-11-30  jbrockmendel@gmail.com                               134
            61934744+phofl@users.noreply.github.com               36
            41443370+ivanovmg@users.noreply.github.com            19
Name: email, dtype: int64
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html does this help you answer your question?

Comment: `value_counts` returns a series. Thats why

Comment: @ombk I understand value_counts is returning a series - but then how are all these series being returned into a bigger series. A series is One-dimensional, if you stack a bunch of series together surely you have Two dimensions? At the very least I would expect an array of series.

Comment: your emails are part of the index no?

Comment: Instead of a dataframe, you're getting a MultiIndex Series. If you wanna a dataframe as output, either return `output.to_frame()` or `top_three.rename('count').rename_axis(['date','email']).reset_index()`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your Groupby is returning.

In your case, you are applying a function on `row['email']` and returning a single `value_counts`, while all other columns in your data are part of index. A `reset_index()` would therefore give you what you need. Meaning, you are returning a multi-index single column output after groupby, which will be returned as a Series instead of a DataFrame.

---

For more clarity on which data structure is returned, we can do a toy experiment.

For example, for the first case, the apply function is applying the lambda function on groups where each group contains a dataframe (check `[i for i in df.groupby(['a'])]` to see what each group contains.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,2,2,3],  'b':[4,5,6,7,8]})
print(df.groupby(['a']).apply(lambda x:x**2))
```

```
#dataframe
   a   b
0  1  16
1  1  25
2  4  36
3  4  49
4  9  64
```

For the second case, we are only applying the lambda function on a series object OR only a single series is being returned. In this case, it doesn't return a dataframe and instead returns a series.

```
print(df.groupby(['a'])['b'].apply(lambda x:x**2))
```

```
#series
0    16
1    25
2    36
3    49
4    64
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

This can be solved simply by -

```
print(df.groupby(['a'])[['b']].apply(lambda x:x**2))
```

```
#dataframe
    b
0  16
1  25
2  36
3  49
```